# Is there a daily list of diversions?

Tags: commercial-aviation

Is there a way to find a daily list of commercial flight diversions that have occurred?  If not, is there any way to compile one from available data?  Extra points if you can also get the reason.

Answer (score 2):

No. Diversions can happen for all sorts of reasons, and often on very short notice. Info about diversions is not communicated and compiled systematically. Generally speaking, only the crew, ATC, airline, original destination and actual destination airport will know, none of which have any interest in publishing the data.

Comment: True, however (albeit off-topic on this site) one could attempt to compile such a list from publicly available sources (eg some flight-tracking sites show "diverted" status as it is pretty easy for them to detect that the actual landing airport is not the published destination for said flight #), so that is not a strict, definite "No"

Comment: @DeepSpace That would never be a complete list as such services do not have perfect coverage. They also don't necessarily know the intended destination of a flight. The same flight number does not always go to the same airport. This is especially true for cargo flights, where the destination sometimes changes very shortly before departure.

Comment: FlightAware in the USA for example has access to some limited information directly from the FAA. For filed IFR flights they know the intended departure and arrival airports and will even receive route updates in near-real time if the flight's route is amended in the ATC system.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the passengers will know. ;)